For @EnableFeignClients annotation, I'm getting an error stating Invalid bean definition
I've tried connecting the services multiple times but I'm unable to figure out this error

My Eureka server is live
I'm trying to connect the product service with the order service

This is my Main class
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class OrderManagementServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderManagementServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

This is my ProductClient Interface
package com.order_management_service.Order.Management.Service.externalService;


import com.order_management_service.Order.Management.Service.DTO.Product;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@FeignClient(name = "PRODUCT-CATALOG-SERVICE")
public interface ProductClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    Product findById(@PathVariable Long id);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "{id}")
    ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product product);
}

This is my Project Structure
Order-Management-Service/
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   └── com.order_management_service.Order.Management.Service/
│   │   │       ├── controller/
│   │   │       │   └── OrderController.java           # Handles API endpoints
│   │   │       ├── DTO/
│   │   │       │   └── OrderDTO.java                  # Data Transfer Object for orders
│   │   │       ├── externalService/
│   │   │       │   └── ProductClient.java             # Manages interactions with Product service
│   │   │       ├── repository/
│   │   │       │   └── OrderRepository.java           # Data access layer for orders
│   │   │       ├── services/
│   │   │       │   └── OrderService.java              # Business logic for managing orders
│   │   │       └── OrderManagementServiceApplication.java  # Main application class
│   │   └── resources/
│   │       ├── application.properties                 # Application configuration
│   │       └── static/                                # Optional: Static files (if any)
│   │       └── templates/                             # Optional: Template files (if any)
└── pom.xml                                            # Maven build file (if applicable)

I've tried to connect with the help of

Spring Boot Guide
ChatGpt
Youtube Videos

But None of the worked
